# contradicting results for environment-parent and environment-has-parent? in MIT-scheme

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

From [the official MIT-scheme texinfo manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Environment-Operations.html#Environment-Operations):

> Environments are first-class objects in MIT/GNU Scheme.  An
>   environment consists of some bindings and possibly a parent
>   environment, from which other bindings are inherited.
>
> ... some other info omitted ...
>
> -- procedure: **environment-has-parent?** *environment*
>        Returns `#t` if *environment* has a parent environment; otherwise
>        returns `#f`.
>
> -- procedure: **environment-parent** *environment*
>        Returns the parent environment of *environment*.  It is an error if
>        *environment* has no parent.

However, in MIT-scheme 10.1.10 on Debian buster 10, I do:

```
(environment-has-parent? (the-environment))

;Value: #t

(environment-parent (the-environment))

;Value: #f
```

These two results seem to contradict. `(the-environment)` *has* a parent, but its parent is `false`. What gives? I was expecting the second call to return some environment and print it, like `;Value: #[environment 12]` or something, but instead it returns a boolean.

**Edit**: as one commenter pointed out below `#f` is an environment and we can get its bindings and everything. Of course, the bindings are not *stored* in the `#f` *object*, but still, that is an incredibly strange and undocumented convention they are using.

Comment: You didn't get an error, so why is it a contradiction?

Comment: It's a contradiction because the results don't appear to be logically consistent. Why must there be an error / stack trace for there to be a contradiction? For example, if I had some instance of a collection data structure for which `empty?` gives true but `length` gives 5 or something. That would intuitively be contradictory, even if there were no stacktrace that gets printed.

Comment: Apparently, `#f` is an environment. `(environment? #f)` returns `#t`. `#f` probably represents the base environment where things like `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `sqrt`, `display`, `newline`, etc. are defined. See the output of `(environment-bindings #f)`.

Comment: ah, what strange convention. I'm sure many others have been confused by this quirk.

Comment: @xdavidliu The difference is that the documentation wouldn't say "`length` is an error if the collection is empty". It would probably say "length is 0 for empty collections", and then returning 5 would be a contradiction.

Comment: @Barmar I see what the misunderstanding is here. In my original question, I wasn't talking about the "error" part of the document at all. That part clearly doesn't apply, and that makes sense. The contradiction I'm talking about is that the environment *does* have a parent environment, but the *value* of that parent environment is `#f`. I found that really weird and contradictory, and I was _not_ talking about the sentence about errors in the documentation.

Comment: Does it say what the type of an environment is? Can you update the question to include a link to the appropriate section of the documentation?

Comment: sure I just updated.

Comment: This is no more a contradiction than saying that, for instance, a list is either a cons or some special magic object which Scheme writes as `()` and which is not a cons.  In Common Lisp the special magic object is all of `()`, `NIL` and boolean false.

Comment: @tfb if there's a similar rule that "an environment is either a special environment type or the false boolean object", then I assure you that rule is much less well-known and much less documented than the rule about lists being either conses or (). The result that the top-level environment is the false object is very unexpected, and as far as I know, not documented anywhere.

Comment: @xdavidliu: The manual says nothing at all about what environments are: it merely defines operations on them.  Environments could be represented by any kind of object at all: you simply should not care about what sort of thing they are.

Comment: @tfb That is most certainly not true. From the excerpt in the manual I posted in the question: "Environments are first-class objects in MIT/GNU Scheme. An environment consists of some bindings and possibly a parent environment, from which other bindings are inherited." That is not merely a definition of operations on environments; it's a bona fide statement of what environments *are* and what they *consist* of. Surely it's not too much of a sin to look at that definition, and be surprised that #f counts as an environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MIT Scheme 10.1.10, `#f` is effectively treated as the top-level environment, and this is simply a convention that is undocumented in the manual.